# Discovering cross category sales using transactions history (Clustering?)

Tags: r, data-mining, clustering, excel

I have a set of sales transaction data containing more than 1 item purchased. Every item sold has a category. I would like figure out which categories are most commonly ordered together.

The data is more or less like this:

```
Transaction ID|Item ID | Sales Quantity|Item Category
1              Apple     1              Fruit
1              Banana    1              Fruit
1              Carrot    2              Vegetable
2              Carrot    1              Vegetable
2              Ice Cream 2              Dessert
3              Squash    2              Vegetable
3              Chocolate 2              Dessert
4              Apple     1              Fruit
4              Carrot    1              Vegetable
4              Doughnut  1              Dessert
```

Just eyeballing above you can see that there are a high amount of vegetable-dessert pairings on the same transaction. But now imagine that we have 250,000+ transactions in the data set and dozens of categories. I'm looking to discover cross category sales only. Not interested in Apples and Bananas (Fruit-Fruit) pairs.

I think I can teach myself how to code the analysis, but I'm just not sure what this is called or what to Google. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your data can be re-ordered to look like this:

```
Transaction ID | Items
1                {Apple, Banana, Carrot}
2                {Carrot, Ice Cream}
```

This kind of data set is trivial for [association rule mining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning). A very simple and well-known algorithm of this kind is the [Apriori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm). I'm certain there are packages for executing this algorithm in R.

For the restriction of "discover cross category sales only", you can just post-prune the generated rules, ie. let the algorithm generated inter-category sales and then remove those later, which should be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Mephy's answer, I wanted to illustrate a little bit more. Association rule mining, which is also called 'Market Basket Analysis'.

Based on your question, Googling market basket analysis will give you more results and there are [many](http://www.salemmarafi.com/code/market-basket-analysis-with-r/) examples and posts on getting started in R.

For example `arules` is a great package for this type of analysis in R. Good luck!